# Create a string with a variable interpolated, assign a value to that variable afterwards and have the string print with the assigned value?

Tags: coffeescript

What I'm hoping for is something to this effect:

```
str = "This is a #{testing}"
testing = "test"
console.log(str)

# => "This is a test"
```

The use case doesn't make switching the order of the variable definitions efficient, so I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately `"This is a #{testing}"` is just shorthand for `"This is a " + testing` so what you're proposing won't work. Using `str = (testing) -> "This is a #{testing}"` and `console.log(str(testing))` might be an option. A JavaScript implementation of `prinft` might be another option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There's not a way to "re-evaluate" the string or anything?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything sane to do (other than using a function instead of a string).

Comment: Sanity is always preferred, though that's actually not a bad idea....

Comment: You could try creating an object and overriding `toString` but then you'd have to trick JavaScript into calling `toString` with something ugly like `some_string + your_object`. I think an explicit function or a template system would be better, especially when you come back to this code in six months.

Comment: The function thing, I mean. Pass the variable names into a function, and then that function returns the string. Essentially that's just creating the array each time it's called, yes, but I guess there's no snazzy way of templating a string before the variable is defined.